Go back button makes page reset for infinite scroll in Remix.run
I am new to Remix.run and want to implement Infinite Scroll. The infinite scroll is working fine. However, when I click one of the movies on page three or four and click the go back button, I see the first page only and the scroll stays bottom of the page.
I would like not to reset to page 1 after clicking the go back button on 3~4 pages and the same scroll position where I clicked the movie.
I referred https://github.com/ahmedrizwan/remix-infinite-scroll/blob/main/app/routes/index.tsx
import { Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Link, json, useFetcher, useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import PageMargin from "~/component/PageMargin";
import { MovieResult } from "~/types/fetchTypes";

interface Movie {
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  genre_ids: number[];
  id: number;
  original_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number;
}

interface Dates {
  maximum: string;
  minimum: string;
}

interface MoviesResponse {
  dates: Dates;
  page: number;
  results: Movie[];
  total_pages: number;
  total_results: number;
}

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const page = url.searchParams.get("page") || "1";

  const apiUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?language=en-US&page=${page}`;
  const res = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `${process.env.SOME_SECRET}`,
    },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch now playing movies");
  }

  const data = await res.json();
  return json(data);
}

const InfiniteScroller = (props: {
  children: any;
  loading: boolean;
  loadNext: () => void;
}) => {
  const { children, loading, loadNext } = props;
  const scrollListener = useRef(loadNext);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollListener.current = loadNext;
  }, [loadNext]);

  const onScroll = () => {
    const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    const scrollDifference = Math.floor(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY);
    const scrollEnded = documentHeight == scrollDifference;

    if (scrollEnded && !loading) {
      scrollListener.current();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default function Index() {
  const nowPlayingMovies = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const fetcher = useFetcher<MoviesResponse>();
  const [items, setItems] = useState<MoviesResponse>(nowPlayingMovies);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!fetcher.data || fetcher.state === "loading") {
      return;
    }

    if (fetcher.data) {
      const newItems = fetcher.data.results;
      setItems((prevAssets) => ({
        ...prevAssets,
        results: [...prevAssets.results, ...newItems],
      }));
    }
  }, [fetcher.data]);

  return (
    <PageMargin>
      <Typography variant="h6" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        Now Playing Movies
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h6" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        From {items.dates.minimum}
      </Typography>
      <InfiniteScroller
        loadNext={() => {
          const page = fetcher.data
            ? fetcher.data.page + 1
            : nowPlayingMovies.page + 1;
          const query = `?index&page=${page}`;
          console.log(query);
          fetcher.load(query);
        }}
        loading={fetcher.state === "loading"}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexFlow: "wrap",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          {items.results.map((nowPlayingMovie: MovieResult) => (
            <Card
              key={nowPlayingMovie.id}
              sx={{ width: 300, margin: "40px 20px" }}
            >
              <Link to={`/movie/detail/${nowPlayingMovie.id}`}>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  height="250"
                  src={
                    "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" +
                    nowPlayingMovie.poster_path
                  }
                  alt={nowPlayingMovie.original_title}
                />
              </Link>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                  {nowPlayingMovie.original_title}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                  sx={{
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                    display: "-webkit-box",
                    WebkitLineClamp: "3",
                    WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
                  }}
                  variant="body2"
                  color="text.secondary"
                >
                  {nowPlayingMovie.overview
                    ? nowPlayingMovie.overview
                    : "No overview for this movie."}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroller>
    </PageMargin>
  );
}


If someone has stuck with it, you can either store it in session storage or use Jotai or context for the page and scroll position.
